# MYSQL Selecting Emoji in Where Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, collation

I have a weird issue in MYSQL Table

My table have column with varchar **utf8mb4** charset and **utf8mb_unicode_ci** collation which has list of emoji and some other strings.

Issue is that whenever i select a single emoji (Eg: **select * from tbl_codes where  where code = ''**), I get other emojis also ( ,,͏)

Also below query returns always 1

```
select '' = '';
```

Comment: Could it be due to the fact that it is doing type comparison

Comment: "type" -- no.  "collation" -- yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

> ```
>  SELECT '' = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
>  
>  SELECT '' = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
> ```
>
> ```
> | '?' = '?' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
> | ---------------------------------------: |
> |                                        0 |
>
> | '?' = '?' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
> | ---------------------------------------: |
> |                                        1 |
> ```

From the document of Mysql [10.3.1 Collation Naming Conventions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-names.html)

> Collation names for Unicode character sets may include a version number to indicate the version of the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA) on which the collation is based. UCA-based collations without a version number in the name use the version-4.0.0 UCA weight keys. For example:
>
> - utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci is based on UCA 5.2.0 weight keys (http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/5.2.0/allkeys.txt).
> - utf8mb4_unicode_ci (with no version named) is based on UCA 4.0.0 weight keys (http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/4.0.0/allkeys-4.0.0.txt).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01b94468beb99af8a127fb411ea1a689)*

Comment: If you are using MySQL 8.0, use one of the collations based on Unicode 9.0.0; it is even newer.

Comment: But this one also return true 
 SELECT '♥' = 'ํํํํํํ♥' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;